# Ajax call for submit form without refreshing page in MVC5

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need some help on submitting form from MVC view wihtout refreshing page but it appers my bellow ajax code is not working:
//here is ajax call

```
function AjaxCallAndShowMessage(btnClick) {

$('form').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                ShowTimeChangeMessage(); // show an alert message
            }
        });

    return false;
});
```

}

// here is the view

```
 <div id="dialog" title="">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Administration", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("SeTime", new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem{ Text="1 Min", Value = "60" },
        new SelectListItem{ Text="2 Min", Value = "120" },
        new SelectListItem{ Text="3 Min", Value = "180" },
    }, "Select Time")
        <input type="submit" value="Set Time "  
        onclick="AjaxCallAndShowMessage(this)" />
    }
</div>
```

I am not getting data for selected item, which I like to get in controller from dropDownkist "SetTime". May I get some help to making ajax call appropriately for this view. Thanks

Comment: What error you facing!

Comment: I am not getting data for selected item, which I like to get in controller from dropDownkist "SetTime"

Comment: I bet you need to attach to the on form submit event. You may be calling post twice because the button is wired up that way an then in the handler you call submit. In the on form submit you can call your ajax.

Comment: @Zahir put your submit function outside the function.

Comment: @SarathKumar, outside the DoAjaxAndShowMessage() function?

Comment: Yes. you don't have add click event for the submit. It won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will generate a SELECT element with name `SeTime`. So when you submit the form (ajax or normal form submit), the browser will send the selected option value as the value of the form item with key SeTime. It should work assuming you have a parameter with same name in your http post action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Administration(string SeTime)
{
 // to do : Do something with SeTime
 // to do : Return something
}
```

If you are using a view model as your method parameter, make sure it is **set**table so that model binder will be able to set the value from the posted form request.

```
public class YourViewModel
{
  public string SeTime {set;get;}
  // other properties here
}
```

Also i see a small problem with your UI code. With your current code, when user clicks on the submit button, it calls the `AjaxCallAndShowMessage` js function, which adds a `submit` event handler to the form. So when user clicks the second time, It register the event handler again to the same form. That means it will make 2 ajax calls now. When user clicks for 3rd time, It will register the event handler again and it will make 3 calls now. This goes on!!!

All you have to do is register once. If you remove the onclick from the html markup and go the onobutrusive javascript way,

```
<input type="submit" value="Set Time "   />
```

and register the submit event handler in the document ready event,

```
$(function () {

    $('form').submit(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
               alert("Ajax call is done");
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Do I need to set form id instead of $('form')

Comment: The jQuery selector `$('form')` will return all form elements in the page. So if you have multiple forms, It is better to use a specific selector like the form id or other form attributes.

Comment: Not working is a very broad statement. What specifically is not working ? Do you have an js errors in your browser console ? What do you see in the console (dev tools)? If you have any other js error when the page loads, your js code might not work

Comment: Yes, I got the error it says " System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: SetLogOffTime."

Comment: `SetLogOffTime` is not part of your original question. So i am not sure what the code deals with that does. You need to fix it. But your ajax form submit code should work fine. I suggest you comment out the code which is giving you the trouble ( dev tools console should show the line number) and narrow down your problem and fix it.

Comment: thanks, I am basically passing the SetLogOffTime as dropdown list value to controller. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

instead of using jquery,ajax to submit the form, use  @Ajax.BeginForm
it works same as jquery ajax call,It posts the form without refreshing the page

```
<div id="dialog" title="">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Administration", "Home", new AjaxOptions
                {
                    OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
                    OnFailure = "OnFailure",
                    LoadingElementId = "progress"
                }))
     {

      @Html.DropDownList("SeTime", new List<SelectListItem>
        {
         new SelectListItem{ Text="1 Min", Value = "60" },
         new SelectListItem{ Text="2 Min", Value = "120" },
         new SelectListItem{ Text="3 Min", Value = "180" },
         }, "Select Time")
       <input type="submit" value="Set Time" />
      }
     }

 </div>
```

for more information follow [this link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-AjaxBeginForm-Tutorial-with-example.aspx)